# I need a spatial query for SQL Server to return the ten closest locations

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and vb.net to create a .asmx webservice, and using SQL Server 2008, but the query below provides all address's in the database.  What I need is to modify the query below into a spatial query that returns the ten closest locations.  The Lat and Long are decimals but there is a Geography Column called [Location] in the database.  Help!

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetFuelStops(ByVal Lat as Double, ByVal Long as Double) As FuelStop()
    Dim resultList = New List(Of FuelStop)()

    Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection()
    sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Example_DB;User ID=Turd;Password=Fergison"
    Dim sql = <sql>
        SELECT
            [Physical_Address_Street]
            , [Physical_Address_Local]
            , [Physical_Address_State]
            , [Physical_Address_Zip]
            , [Lat]
            , [Long]
            , [Phone_Number]
        FROM Gas_Stations
        WHERE Location_Type = 1
        </sql>

    Dim command As New SqlCommand()
    command.CommandText = CStr(sql)
    command.Connection = sqlCon
    sqlCon.Open()

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Dim fuelStop = New FuelStop()
            fuelStop.Physical_Address_Street = reader.GetString(0)
            fuelStop.Physical_Address_Local = reader.GetString(1)
            fuelStop.Physical_Address_State = reader.GetString(2)
            fuelStop.Physical_Address_Zip = reader.GetString(3)
            fuelStop.Phone_Number = reader.GetString(4)

            resultList.Add(fuelStop)
        End While
       End Using
    End Using
Return resultList.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToArray()

End Function
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are plenty of resources just one google search away. Search for "STDistance"...

Comment: I have tried googling it but I don't really know enough about it to even attempt it.  I am fairly new to Database programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to take a closer look at the geospatial features in SQL Server instead of asking for the actual solution. It is a powerful feature but might decrease performance if used in the wrong way.

The following query should do what you want:

```
DECLARE @center GEOGRAPHY

SET @center = geography::Point(46.969345, 8.592703, 4326)

SELECT TOP 10
    [Physical_Address_Street]
    , [Physical_Address_Local]
    , [Physical_Address_State]
    , [Physical_Address_Zip]
    , [Lat]
    , [Long]
    , [Phone_Number]
FROM Gas_Stations
WHERE Location_Type = 1
ORDER BY @center.STDistance(Location) ASC
```

Comment: I haven't used these built-in features but have been doing similar queries with a home-grown alternative to R-TREES. Would the query above select ALL rows, computing the distance from @center for each row, sorting by that calculated distance, limiting the result to the top 10? What if there are a million gas stations in the table? Do the geospatial features employ any sort of preprocessing so they can narrow the computation down to a smaller subset of rows?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, but I can't tell you more about the optimizations made by the SQL Server. I'm using a query similar to this on a table with a continuously growing number of rows. Until now it performs pretty well. Maybe I can tell you more once I reached a millions records or found the time to take a closer look at the geospatial feature...

Comment: Without preprocessing, I ran into performance issues with only 60,000 rows doing provider-proximity searches. We get a set of 10,000 addresses which are geocoded with lat/lon and then for each address we have to compute the average distance to the three closest medical practicioners (60K rows in that table).  If you have to query 60,000 rows 10,000 times you like a little optimization :-)

Comment: Zombie I just wanted to say thank you for showing this.  It worked like a charm.  I have been doing programming for a few years but I am really new to databases.  Just a thank you again.

Comment: And I did look into Geospatial features and will continue to do so and learn them.